# Display Master page header on only one page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have master page and default page .

I would like to place logo only on default page and and text on all consecutive pages is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is.   You can do it in jquery or in the code behind.
In vb.net you could put this in the default.aspx onload event:

```
Dim i As Image = Master.FindControl("Image1")

        i.Visible =False
```

In jquery you can put code in the master page and check the document.url:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    if (document.URL.indexOf('default.aspx') > 0) {
       document.getElementById("Image1").style.display = 'none';
}

});
```